# In python asyncio, is it possible to call another task without waiting for it to finish?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Currently task1 need to wait for task2 to finish. Now I need task2 looks like another thread without affecting the execution of task1, how to achieve that?

```
async def task2():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("task2")


async def task1():
    await task2()
    print("task1")
async def main(loop):
    task = loop.create_task(task1())
    await task

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`asyncio.gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) to run each task that you pass to it concurrently. The code inside each coroutine executes synchronously until it reaches an `await` keyword where it passes control back to the event loop.

If you want to `task2` to be "initiated" by `task1`, you can use [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) to wait until an event is set in task2 and set the event in task1.

See the revised example. Both tasks run concurrently using `asyncio.gather`. But `task2` doesn't do anything until the event is set from `task1`.

```py
import asyncio

async def task2(event):
    print("starting task2")
    await event.wait()
    print("event set")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("task2 end")


async def task1(event):
    print("starting task1")
    event.set()
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("task1 end")

async def main(loop):
    event = asyncio.Event()

    await asyncio.gather(
        task1(event),
        task2(event)
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
    loop.close()
```

I added a few more print statements, a 3 second sleep to `task2`, and a 5 second sleep to `task1`. Since they are running concurrently, the output will be:

```
starting task1
starting task2
event set
task2 end
task1 end
```

Comment: what if task2 is triggered by task1?

Comment: the code inside `task1` execute synchronously until it releases control back to the event loop when it runs into an `await` keyword. you can get around this using events. See my edited answer above